# Convert Looping from php to twig

Tags: php, twig

I want to change the command from php to twig :

```php
<?php for($__i = 0; $__i < sizeof($s_opts); $__i++) { ?>

<option value="<?php echo $s_opts[$__i]['id']; ?>"><?php echo $s_opts[$__i]['name']; ?></option> 

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: So what did you try so far?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way of doing this

```
{% for opt in s_opts %}
    <option value="{{ opt.id }}">{{ opt.name }}</option> 
{% endfor %}
```

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/for.html